# How many segmentations are possible for a string length N?

Tags: combinatorics, strings

I have a string with length N. I would like to know how many segmentations are possible to it. 
Consider the example `abcdc` the number of N = 5
All possible segmentations are

```
['abcdc']
['abcd', 'c']
['abc', 'dc']
['abc', 'd', 'c']
['ab', 'cdc']
['ab', 'cd', 'c']
['ab', 'c', 'dc']
['ab', 'c', 'd', 'c']
['a', 'bcdc']
['a', 'bcd', 'c']
['a', 'bc', 'dc']
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'cdc']
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'dc']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
```

Then what will happen  when  `my N tends to infinity` . Any closed form equations?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1706301/

Comment: @Kaveh Migrated from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are n-1 points where you can break the string. Each is independent of the others. Therefore there are $2^{n-1}$ possibilities to break the string.

Comment: What will happen when N -> Infinity ?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n-1} = \infty$

Comment: How is it possible ?

Comment: The limit of any unbounded increasing function is infinity. Ask on [math.se] if it is not clear for you.

Comment: Yeah. That is from limits and continuity