# Why is the time complexity of the word break O(2^N)

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to understand the time complexity of the word break problem which uses the backtracking recursive approach. It is O(2^N).

Well lets take an example abcd as input with the recursive approach naive, the recursion tree will be something like this

```
                      abcd
                     /.... \
                    /\     /\
                   a bcd..abc d
                     /  \
                    /\ 
                   b  cd
```

So eventually at the end of the tree, I mean the leaves the count will be (2^N). is that right?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the problem?

Comment: @Eugene. Nvm found the answer here - https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54700/how-many-segmentations-are-possible-for-a-string-length-n

Comment: Here is the answer for my question - https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54700/how-many-segmentations-are-possible-for-a-string-length-n